What's with all the wordplay on Rosh Hashana?
I am dividing my question into 3 parts:

We all know that you are not meant to sleep so much on Rosh Hashana, so that you don't have a "sleepy" year.
At the Rosh Hashana meal at night, we have many Simanim. For example, we eat an apple dipped in honey, so that we will have a "sweet" year. We eat the head of a fish, so that this year we should be on top, like a head, and not on bottom, like a tail. And that is only a few of the Simanim we have on Rosh Hashana.
Many people began to make their own Simanim for Rosh Hashana. The most famous one created is the lettuce, raisin, and celery. People eat all three of them to say - "Let us (lettuce) have a raise in (raisin) our salary (celery).


So, my question is what is up with all this wordplay? Isn't it all a bit childish for such a holy day?

I'm not sure where, but i remember someone writing that its not the actual eating the food, but the prayer you should have in mind (e.g. may all of our enemies be ended) and eating it is a imprint of the prayer, like the navi shmuel ripping shauls cloak to tell him that the next person to rip your coat will be king

A better example for #3 is the actual minhag of eating carrots because it's a homonym for "more" in Yiddish. But most of the minhagim are about symbolism, not mere wordplay.

Make sure to have soup if you want to have a super new year

I will try to address all your points which seem to play in similar ways but may come from different sources.

Sleep on Rosh Hashanah. A deep analysis made by Rabbi Laufer in the book "Rendezvous with G-d" draws strong parallels between experience of the Jewish people at the moment of Giving of the Torah at Sinai and the minhagim of Rosh Hashanah. The connection is discussed here and here. Because of midrash Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer 41:7:


Rabbi Chanina said: || In the third month the day is double the night, and the Israelites slept until two hours of the day, for sleep on the day of the (feast of) 'Azereth is pleasant, the night being short. And Moses went forth and came to the camp of the Israelites, and he aroused the Israelites from their sleep, saying to them: Arise ye from your sleep, for behold, your G-d desires to give the Torah to you.

To correct the words of the midrash, we have a minhag not to sleep on Rosh Hashanah (and later the midrash became a source for another minhag not to sleep on the night of Shavuos once coffee became available).


During the times of the Talmud, the Jewish communities in the Persian empire often faced persecutions from the followers of Zoroastreanism, the old official Persian religion. Many of the established Rosh Hashanah simanim and minhagim externally appear similar to those of Zoroastreans celebrating Nowruz (their New Year) and other holidays. Haft Sin (Persian: هفت‌ سین‎, originally هفت‌ چین: Haft Chin1) is an Iranian tradition of a festive table for the holiday of Nowruz. Haft Sin includes 7 elements, the names of which begin with the letter ﺱ - "Sin", the fifteenth letter of the Persian alphabet: سیر (sir) - garlic, a symbol of medicine; سیب (sib) - apples, a symbol of beauty and health; سبزه (sabzeh) - sprouts (wheat or lentils), a symbol of the revival of nature; سنجد (senjed) - lokh, a symbol of love; سرکه (serke) - vinegar, a symbol of wisdom and patience; سمنو (samanu) - bread pudding, a symbol of prosperity; سماق (somag) - sumac, a symbol of dawn.

A "book of wisdom" is also commonly included, which might be, Avesta, the Shahnameh, the Quran or the Divān of Hafez. They place on the table sweets, nuts, decorated eggs, a mirror, candles, goldfish, as well as a ribbon or any composition of traditional Iranian flowers (green-white-red), or the flag itself are often present on the table. Coins (سکه sekke), hyacinth (سنبل sonbol), and clock (ساعت suat also pronounced so-at) are sometimes included too.
It is common practice on the eve of Nowruz to bring "Haft Sin" to the graves of relatives so that the deceased can also take part in the holiday.
Externally, it appears that the Jewish customs were observed on purpose so that the surrounding Persians did not think that the Jews were practicing Judaism. However, the Jewish customs have Jewish sources:

The apple in honey. Apple comes from the Shir HaShirim 2:3, and honey in the ancient world was “food of kings”, for example, Yaakov avinu included honey as a gift to the Egyptian Vice Roy (who turned out to be Yosef). Regarding Apple we have Gemara Shabbos 88a written in the contexts of Matan Torah:


Rabbi Ḥama, son of Rabbi Ḥanina, said: What is the meaning of that which is written: “As an apple tree among the trees of the wood, so is my beloved among the sons. Under its shadow I delighted to sit and its fruit was sweet to my taste” (Song of Songs 2:3)? Why were the Jewish people likened to an apple tree? It is to tell you that just as this apple tree, its fruit grows before its leaves, so too, the Jewish people accorded precedence to “We will do” over “We will hear.”


Maharal miPrague in Chudushei Aggados (Horayos perek 4, 60:1) notes that Jewish simanim allude to the qualities of Jewish heroes that we expect as ushpizin-guests on the holiday of Succos, which comes two weeks after Rosh Hashanah:
For example, zucchini or pumpkin (קָרָא) - to declare nullified bad decrees and proclaim (קרי) merit, which alludes to Avraham. Avraham chose to follow the path of good commandments, which gave merit and protected him from troubles.
Fenugreek, beans (רוביא) - to increase merit (רובה) allude to Yitzchak. Yitzchak, through self-control, re-dug up his father's wells that other people buried, and his harvest was increased 100 times.
Leek (כָרָתֵי) - so that all who hate and envy be cut off (כרת), and friends remain alludes to Yaakov. Yaakov chose the path of truth, thanks to which he defeated angels and his enemies, since the truth swallows any lie.
One can draw several other such derushim about all traditional simanim connecting them to also Moshe, Aharon, Yosef, and David.



When people make various wishes, which are not connected to Jewish sources, there is a danger that they look like the described customs of Zoroastreans. All such expressions, if one does not have a reputable source, ideally should be worked out with the personal rav to see if they are kosher.

